# how to add webform in sharepoint hosted app?

Tags: 2013

I want to create a webform app in Sharepoint 2013, when I create a new project I'm asked what kind of project I want

if I choose "sharepoint hosted" it doesnt allow me to add webforms, how can I add webforms?

if I choose "Provider hosted" I got problems when running the app, it says that apps are not permitted in the sharepoint site, I have tried to follow the instructions here http://sharepointchick.com/archive/2012/07/29/setting-up-your-app-domain-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx but without luck, there is another tutorial out there less complicated?

Comment: Could it be that you provided URL of a site that doesn't have the apps sideloading Feature enabled (ie. a site that hasn't been created using the Developer Site template)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, SharePoint hosted apps do not allow web forms! It really does not allow any logic not being JavaScript.

You must use provider hosted apps for web forms, but regarding you not getting it working, there must be some step(s) you have skipped in the configuration (the link you provided is a 404)

Answer (score 0):

For setting app domain you can use FQDN(Fully qualified domain name) of your machine for testing purpose. You can start from following links:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142381(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142381%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179901(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179901%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/Step-by-Step-approach-to-create-a-Provider-Hosted-Application-in-SharePoint-2013